# Solution of $\tan^{-1} \sqrt{x^2 + x} +\sin^{-1} \sqrt{x^2 + x + 1} = \pi/2$

Tags: trigonometry, inverse-function

My attempt at question

$\tan^{-1} \sqrt{x^2 + x} +\sin^{-1} \sqrt{x^2 + x + 1} = \pi/2$

using the identity
$\tan^{-1}(\sqrt{x^2 + x} + \sqrt{x^2+x+1/-x^2-x}/[1- \sqrt{x^2+x)(x^2+x+1/-x^2-x)}]$=π/2

$\sqrt{x^2+x} + \sqrt{x^2+x+1/-x^2-x}/[1- \sqrt{(x^2+x)(x^2+x+1/-x^2-x)}$] = 1/0

1- $\sqrt{x^2+x)(x^2+x+1/-x^2-x)}$=0

1=$\sqrt{-x^2-x-1}$

x^2+x+2=0 but this gives complex solution and the answer is 0,-1

Can someone point out my mistake?

Comment: Your work is difficult to read as is. Please properly typeset your question using MathJax. [This page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) should give you a start at learning how to typeset mathematics here so that your posts say what you want them to, and also look good.

Comment: I have corrected the initial identity. Please do the remaining part using what @Brian has indicated.

Comment: I have edited my question to my best potential. Please point out the mistake in my answer. I know there are other ways to solve it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need $\sqrt{x^2+x+1}\le 1$, so $x^2+x\le 0$. On the other hand, you also need $x^2+x\ge0$, so the only points where the left-hand side makes sense are $-1$ and $0$.

Now try substituting $x=0$ and $x=-1$ to find whether they satisfy the equation.

You seem to be using identities that hold, but only when the terms they represent exist. It is true that
$$
\arcsin t=\arctan\frac{t}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}
$$
when $1-t^2\ne0$, with possible extension when (ab)using $\infty$. For your case it's handier to set $y=x^2+x$, to keep things simpler. Then
$$
1-(\sqrt{y+1})^2=-y^2
$$
and therefore the expression can be written
$$
\arctan \sqrt{y}+\arctan\frac{\sqrt{y+1}}{\sqrt{-y}}
$$
and the condition $y=0$ clearly shows up.

Going on with further identities is a waste of time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but please point out the mistake in my attempt.I have edited it to best of my knowledge

Comment: @RituKhanna I'm not sure about those identities, but when you write $1/0$ there's surely something amiss.

Comment: Well I have used the identity tan−1 x + tan−1 y = tan−1(
x+y/
1-xy)   which further gives  x+y/1-xy= tanπ/2 and  we know tan π/2 is 1/0

Comment: @RituKhanna But you have $\sin^{-1}$ in the second term, not $\tan^{-1}$.

Comment: Yes and thats why i have written sin-1√(x^2+x+1) as tan-1√(x^2+x+1/-x^2-x)

Comment: @RituKhanna Didn't check the details, but identities only hold when the expressions make sense and, in your case, they don't unless $x\in\{0,-1\}$.

Comment: @RituKhanna I added some more comments.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a=\tan^{-1}\sqrt{x^2+x}$ and $b=\sin^{-1}\sqrt{x^2+x+1}$.

Then $\tan^2 a=x^2+x$ and $\sin^2 b=x^2+x+1$

$\sec^2a=x^2+x+1=\sin^2b=\sin^2(\frac{\pi}{2}-a)=\cos^2a$

So, $\cos^4a=1$ and hence $a=k\pi$, ($k\in\mathbb{Z}$).

$x^2+x=0$.

Answer (score 1):

HInt:

Let $y=\arctan\sqrt{x^2+x}\ge0\implies x^2+x=\tan^2y,0\le y<\dfrac\pi2\implies\cos y\ge0$

$\implies\sin^{-1}(\sec y)=\dfrac\pi2-y$

$\sec y=\sin\left(\dfrac\pi2-y\right)=\cos y$

$\implies\cos y=1$ as $\cos y\ge0$

$\implies\sqrt{x^2+x+1}=1$